# Partial View Text box value is not updating based on dropdown value

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a dropdownlist when i select the dropdown value and click edit button it should open partial view with the value selected from dropdown in the textboxfor. But when i open the page which contains dropdownlist first time it works perfect but when i close the partial view without doing any operation in partial view and agin when i select the dropdownlist value and click edit button it takes the previous selected value not the latest one.
Following is my code.

```
    View With Ajax call to controller.  $(document).ready(function () {

        if ('@TempData["message"]' == "updated") {
            toastr.success('Updated Successfuly');
        }
        else if ('@TempData["message"]' == "already") {
            toastr.error('Domain Already Exists');
        }            
        else if ('@TempData["message"]' == "deleted") {
            toastr.success('Deleted Successfuly');
        }


    });

    function del() {
        var url = "/UserGroupEdit/Delete";
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $.post(url + '/' + id, function (data) {
            $('#ModalPopupContent').html(data);
            $('#myModal').modal('show');

        });
    }
    function dd(mode) {

        if (mode == "Edit") {

            var a = $("#Domain").val();

            if (a != "") {
                var url = "../DomainCRUD/EditDom";

                var id = $("#Domain").val();
                var obj = {
                    InstructionHeader: 'Edit',
                    Domain: id
                }
                alert(a);
                try {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "../DomainCRUD/EditDom",
                        data: obj,
                        async: false,
                        method: "POST",
                        success: function (response) {
                            $('#ModalPopupContent').html(response);
                            $('#myModal').modal('show');

                        }


                    });
                } catch (e) {

                }
            }
            else {

            }

        }
        else if (mode == "Delete") {
            var a = $("#Domain").val();

            if (a != "") {
                var action = confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete");
                if (action) {
                    var url = "../DomainCRUD/EditDom";
                    var id = $("#Domain").val();
                    var obj = {
                        InstructionHeader: 'Delete',
                        Domain: id
                    }
                    try {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "../DomainCRUD/EditDom",
                            data: obj,
                            async: false,
                            method: "POST",
                            success: function (response) {

                                if (response == "exist") {
                                    toastr.error('You cannot Delete this Domain as it is alloted to some users.');
                                }
                                else
                                    toastr.success('Deleted Successfuly');
                            }

                        });
                    } catch (e) {

                    }



                }
                else {

                }
            }
            else {

            }
        }

    }

</script>
```

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


    <div class="content-box">



        <div class="page-title">
            <h2>Add New Domain</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="create-button">
            @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
        </div>

        <div class="content-box dashbord-content-box">

            <div class="label-row">
                <div class="label-cont">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">List of Domains</label>
                </div>
                <div class="label-box">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Domain, ViewBag.GroupType as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "--Select--", new { required = "required", oninvalid = "this.setCustomValidity('Please select Domain')", oninput = "setCustomValidity('')" })

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="button-box">
                <div class="label-cont">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1"></label>
                </div>



                <input type="button" name="submit" value="Edit" onclick="dd('Edit');" class="btn btn-default sub-but" />

                <input type="button" name="submit" value="Delete" onclick="dd('Delete');" class="btn btn-default sub-but" />
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

}
```

My Controller Action.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (Session["Email"] != null && Session["GroupType"].ToString() == "1")
        {
            var res = (from u in db.ConfigurationSettings select u.Domain).FirstOrDefault();
            string[] thisArray = res.Split(',');
            List<string> myList = new List<string>(); 
            myList.AddRange(thisArray);
            ViewBag.GroupType = new SelectList(myList);
            return View();
        }
        else
            return RedirectToAction("LogIn", "Auth");
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditDom(ConfigurationSetting config)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (config.Domain != null)
            {

                if (config.InstructionHeader == "Edit")
                {

                    Session["editeddomain"] = config.Domain;

                    return PartialView("EditDompartial", config);
                }
                else
                {
                    var isexist = (from u in db.Users where u.DomainName == config.Domain select u).Any();
                    if (isexist == false)
                    {
                        Session["editeddomain"] = config.Domain;
                        DeleteDomain();
                        TempData["message"] = "deleted";
                        return JavaScript("location.reload(true)");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        TempData["message"] = "failed";
                        return Content("exist");
                    }
                }

            }
            else
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "DomainCRUD");

        }
        else
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "DomainCRUD");

    }
```

Partial View

```
  <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Domain, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                <div class="login_field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Domain, new { required = "required", htmlAttributes = new { } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Domain, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-4">&nbsp;</div>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" formaction="SaveEditedDomain" class="btn btn-default save-button" />
            </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: ok thanks for mentioning.

Comment: Plz help anyone